pyasn1: Error while decoding DER sequence
I have a DER Sequence which I was able to parse using asn1 module from pycrypto. Now that pycrypto was deprecated, I want to move to pyasn1.
Below is my code snippet:
x = "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"

from pyasn1.codec.der import decoder
decoder.decode(bytes.fromhex(x))

The decode resulted in the error:
"attributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tagSet'")"

I know the error is due to the last sequence (representing NULL without value): 3000.
This was working previously with asn1 from pycrypto (which was deprecated). I wanted to switch my code to pyasn1. Any help?
openssl works fine:
echo "" | xxd -p -r | openssl asn1parse -inform dev
So, error only with pyasn1. Any workaround for this ? Or any options that we can pass while decoding ?

Sorry, it works for me.

FWIW on Ubuntu 18.04 (python3 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 and python3-pyasn1 0.4.2-3build1) I get what looks like the correct result but on 20.04 (3.10.6-1~22.04  and 0.4.8-1) I get no error and only a single <Sequence schema object ...> (not "value") with no trace of the contents, which is clearly wrong. Also you do realize that even though pycrypto is dead, pycryptodome is healthy and claims API compatibility?

@Armali can you please try the above code with the exact input string given ?

@dave_thompson_085 the asn1 functionality from pycryptodome is heavily changed when compared to the one from pycrypto. The same was mentioned in the pycryptodome docs. Since pyasn1 is popular for asn1, wanted to take steps towards pyasn1

@theLearner –
I already did.

@Armali could you please let me know what version of pyasn1 and python you have used ?

pyasn1
Version: 0.1.9, Python 3.5.3
